# Adding Google fonts to an SVG file

Tags: svg, webfonts, google-font-api

I've been trying to add Google fonts to my svg file, since I'm not using it in my html file, but as an image. I've gone through threads on the site looking for solutions, and none of them seem to work. Here's my svg code, any help would be really appreciated!:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 289.226 867.666" width="289.226" height="867.666">

<defs>
<style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" type="text/css">
  @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
</style>
</defs>


<g>
    <g><path d=" M 144.613 0 C 64.746 0 0 64.745 0 144.612 C 0 224.479 64.746 289.222 144.613 289.222" fill="rgb(247,147,30)" /><line x1="144.613" y1="0" x2="144.613" y2="289.222"/><g transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,84.879,191.611)"><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,28.2)" font-family="Raleway" style="font-family:'Raleway, sans-serif';font-weight:400;font-size:30px;font-style:normal;fill:#000000;stroke:none;">we3dx</text></g></g>
    <g><path d=" M 144.613 289.222 C 224.48 289.222 289.226 353.967 289.226 433.834 C 289.226 513.701 224.48 578.444 144.613 578.444" fill="rgb(247,147,30)" /><line x1="144.613" y1="289.222" x2="144.613" y2="578.444"/><g transform="matrix(0,1,-1,0,200.854,362.333)"><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,28.2)" style="font-family:'Raleway';font-weight:400;font-size:30px;font-style:normal;fill:#000000;stroke:none;">wooscape</text></g></g>
    <g><path d=" M 144.613 578.444 C 64.746 578.444 0 643.189 0 723.056 C 0 802.923 64.746 867.666 144.613 867.666" fill="rgb(247,147,30)"/><line x1="144.613" y1="578.444" x2="144.613" y2="867.666"/><g transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,84.879,788.555)"><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,28.2)" style="font-family:'Raleway';font-weight:400;font-size:30px;font-style:normal;fill:#000000;stroke:none;">woostate</text></g></g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try embedding the SVG with an `<object>` tag instead of `<img>`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Hi, thanks for replying, I'm using it as a background-image in my css property right now, because of reasons, is it still possible to change the font?

Comment: I think that would be impossible with a CSS rule like `background-image`, but you might be able to work around by resizing an `<object>` element to fill the viewport.

Comment: @geteds all images including background-image must be self-contained. External references to things like http://fonts.googleapis.com will not work.

Comment: Also, in one of them, you have `font-family:'Raleway, sans-serif';` which looks wrong.  It should be `font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;`